# Shared Function in Asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have a shared ASP.net function on the server that uses a global data-table that gets called from multiple clients using a jquery:

```
 <System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> Public Shared Sub Jquery_input(JqueryStr As String)
  Dim dt As DataTable = HttpContext.Current.Application("GlobalTable")
  Dim i As Integer = 0
  Do Until i = dt.Rows.Count
   If JqueryStr = dt.Rows(i)("VAL") Then
    Exit Do
   End If
   i = i + 1
  Loop
  If i <> dt.Rows.Count Then
   dt.Rows(i)("val1") = s(0)
   dt.Rows(i)("val2") = s(1)
   dt.Rows(i)("val3") = s(2)
   dt.Rows(i)("val4") = s(3)
  End If
  HttpContext.Current.Application("GlobalTable") = dt
 End Sub
```

i do not understand why sometimes this function fails on this line:

```
 dt.Rows(i)("val1") = s(0)
```

it fails because `i` equals 2 and `dt` only has 2 rows. most of the time the IF statement catches this problem but sometimes it gets bypassed? is this because the function is being called by multiple users in an asynchronized fashion?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is this because the function is being called by multiple users in an
>   asynchronized fashion?

May be, may be not -- to know for certain thread-safery should be enforced.
`HttpApplicationState` offers two convenience methods, `Lock` and `UnLock`. Second one usually goes to finally block:

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> Public Shared Sub Jquery_input(JqueryStr As String)
    HttpContext.Current.Application.Lock()
    Try
        ' thread-safe zone 
        ' (at least as long as only this method is concerned)
    Finally
        HttpContext.Current.Application.Unlock()
    End Try
End Sub
```

And there are others means to protect objects in multi-threaded environment, such as `Monitor`.

I will not touch your algorithm, but using indexes might sometimes be error prone, consider referencing objects directly. Example:

```
Dim foundRow As DataRow = Nothing
For Each row as DataRow in dt.Rows
    If JqueryStr = row("VAL") Then
        foundRow = row
    End If
Next
If not (foundRow Is Nothing) Then
    foundRow("val1") = s(0)
    foundRow("val2") = s(1)
    foundRow("val3") = s(2)
    foundRow("val4") = s(3)
End If
```